# Query not working, it is not deleting the values from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drupal website where added a function that will allow the user to delete his account. I tested it and when i click on the button, nothing happens. I echoed out the values $u['meme'] and $u['id'] and they return the right thing which is not processed by the function.

Why my query is not working? Any mysql setting or? 
Thank you!

this comes from configure:

```
//logat = logged in

if(!isset($_SESSION['logat'])) $_SESSION['logat']='';
if($_SESSION['logat'] != '')
{
    $r=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `useri` WHERE id='".$_SESSION['logat']."'"));
    $u['nume']=$r['nume'];
    $u['meme']=$r['meme'];
    $u['id']=$r['id'];
    $u['premiu']=$r['premiu'];
    $u['caracter']=$r['caracter'];
    $u['hits']=$r['hits'];
    $logat='da';
}
```

and the code with the problem:

```
<?php

function Deleteuser($logat){

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `useri` where `meme`={$u['meme']} OR `id` = {$u['id']}");
logout();
}


if($logat=='da') 
{

echo '<button onclick="Deleteuser()">Delete account</button>'; 
}
else
{
echo 'You are not logged in'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Also... Why do you need the `OR` in the delete query - the id should be unique and more than sufficient on its own.

Comment: How do you expect to reach `$u` in scope if it's not passed into the function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this calls a javascript function

```
echo '<button onclick="Deleteuser()">Delete account</button>';
```

and you have created the Deleteuser() php function, which is a totally different thing. You could just do:

```
<?php

function Deleteuser($logat){

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `useri` where `meme`={$u['meme']} OR `id` = {$u['id']}");
logout();
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    //call the function here to delete user
}


if($logat=='da') 
{

echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="delete"><input type="submit" value="Delete account"></form>'; 
}
else
{
echo 'You are not logged in'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: `Deleteuser()` needs to take the user id as a parameter

Comment: It could be posted as well as a hidden field (if cannot be accessed as $_SESSION)

Comment: I'm not sure how your example works.  Instead of echoing a delete button like the OP did, you just output a form with hidden input.  I still don't see how `Deleteuser()` (PHP function) is being called at all or receiving the user id.

Comment: OP did... `onclick="Deleteuser()"` is a javascript call.  When the user clicks on that button, they want the row to be deleted (somehow... magic, probably).  It can be done a few ways.  I just don't fully understand your way.... I'm just asking for clarification.  So I don't need to make a new comment: I still don't get how yours works regardless of js or not.  I agree that the solution does not need js to be done.

Comment: Yes, but my solution does not involve js. If he wants to use js then he'll have to do it with ajax.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong.  I'm asking you to explain how it works a little more.